# Meaning of 彼女だけは普段と変わらなかった

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to understand the following passage and the meaning of 彼女だけは普段と変わらなかった in this context.

I think it means the following: Even after シャロ had changed, she was still the "same" in front of ユラギ. However, for this interpretation I would have expected something like 彼女の前だけは which makes me think that it could mean something different.

> 「すまない、今は詳しく言えないが……彼女には在学中から思うところがあるのだ」
>
> 「ふむ？」
>
> 「妹の事故を境に性格が変わったんだ。貴族のお嬢様らしい振る舞いを覚えたのかと思いもしたが……」
>
> 「そんなに今と違うのか？」
>
> 「どちらかといえば活発で、皆の中心に立って引っ張っていく性格だったな」
>
> 「お嬢様のように感じたんだが……まるっきり違う性格だな。ユラギは何か言ってるのか？」
>
> 「ユラギはああいう性格だからな……　シャロが変わってしまっても**彼女だけは普段と変わらなかった**よ」
>
> 「ああ……それもそうだな」

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「ユラギはああいう性格だからな…… シャロが変わってしまっても彼女だけは普段と変わらなかったよ」

彼女 refers to ユラギ.

"Even after シャロ had changed, she (=ユラギ) was still the same."